# Question regarding partial derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I guess I am asking a very basic and fundamental question on partial derivative, but this is constantly bugging me and I cannot seem to find a satisfying answer, so please forgive me for doing so.

Suppose we have...
$$f(a)= e^a +a^2$$
If we take the partial derivative of f with respect to $e^a$ i.e $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (e^a)}$ do we just ignore the $a^2$ term and assume it as a constant? And when we do a normal derivative $\frac{df}{d(e^a)}$ then we cannot ignore the $a^2$ term and we have to consider  $\frac{d(a^2)}{d(e^a)}$ which is $\frac{2a}{e^a}$. Is this right?
I do not quite understand why we do that in partial derivative since $a^2$ is not independent of $e^a$ and I have seen it mostly being used in chain rules and not independently as such. Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: What do you mean by differentiating with respect to $e^a$?  Here $f$ is a function of one variable, $a$, it doesn't really make sense to differentiate with respect to $e^a$.

Comment: Whether It does or does not make sense is another issue. My question here is what is the difference between $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (e^a)}$ and $\frac{d(f)}{d(e^a)}$. For you, it looks like f is a function of one variable. But what if $f$ is a function of 2 other functions dependent on $a $like $u(a)=e^a$ and $v(a)=a^2$. So what I'm asking is if there is any difference between $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (u(a))}$ and $\frac{df}{d(u(a))}$

Comment: The answer is the same whether we use a total derivative or a partial derivative. This is proven by showing that there is only ever one independent variable. There is no way to change $e^a$ without changing $a^2$, there is no way to change $a^2$ without changing $e^a$, so the two functions are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule says $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial g(a)}\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a}.$$ Set $g(a)=e^a$. We can compute the other terms:
$$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a}=e^a+2a$$ and $$\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a}=e^a.$$ We can isolate to find
$$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial g(a)}=\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial g(a)}{\partial a}\right)^{-1}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial e^a}=\frac{e^a+2a}{e^a}=1+2a e^{-a}.$$

In general, for multivariable problems, one would need to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the transformation and use its inverse here.

An alternative answer: set $x=e^a$. Then $f(x)=x+[\ln (x)]^2$. Taking the derivative, we find, as before,
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=1+2\ln(x) \frac{\partial \ln (x)}{\partial x}=1+2\ln(x) \frac{1}{ x}=1+2\frac{a}{e^a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at it, based on what I take you to be asking. You have $f(a) = e^a + a^2$. Notice that $a^2 = \log^2e^a$. Then, if $x = e^a$, you have $g(x) = x + \log^2 x = f(a)$. So, the derivative you're after should be $\partial_x f = 1 + \frac{2\log x}{x}$. This is basically what you wrote.